# Angular 2 : How to reuse common code for other apps to use?

Tags: angular, reusability, ng-modules

Need suggestions on how to reuse common code across angular apps.

We started developing an app with angular2 for some specific needs but at a later point realized that more apps will follow and try to reuse ALL or ONE of the common services and components in other apps.

To solve the purpose, we decided to move the common code to a separate standalone app and create ngModules for these common components which should be consumable for other apps to use. Is this a correct way of doing it ?
If yes, how to consume these services in my app ?
If not, What is the best way to import common modules into multiple Apps ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can then share them by creating an npm package and depending on what other tools you have you can use the them to share them.

For public packages you can push it onto the npm repository or they can be made private by using some of the tools.

If you have a git repository you would be able to use npm and install that git repository. `npm install git://github.com/npm/npm.git --save` if your git repository was npm on github.